# Any reason not to always use Fn::Sub in place of Fn::Ref or Fn::GetAtt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've found myself in the practice of always using Fn::Sub in place of Fn::Ref or Fn::GetAtt (or more accurately !Sub instead of !Ref or !GetAtt).

I find it easier to just use !Sub as I can use it to get the ref or an attribute in object.property style.

Is there any drawback to doing so?

Comment: Fn::Sub,  Fn::Ref, Fn::GetAtt have different usage.
There is some case that suits for each function.
You can't use !Sub instead of !Ref or !GetAtt, because it's really depends on the case.
What is your case anyway?

Comment: When you say you can't use !Sub instead of !Ref or !GetAtt it's different than the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html): _If you specify template parameter names or resource logical IDs, such as ${InstanceTypeParameter}, AWS CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Ref intrinsic function. If you specify resource attributes, such as ${MyInstance.PublicIp}, AWS CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function._ So what do you mean you cant?